# Construct array based on key & values of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I'm trying to create a code that will receive inputs like this:

```
{
  "11": {
    "08/2011": 1
  },
  "12": {
    "08/2011": 2
  },
  "13": {
    "08/2011": 3
  }
}
```

And will output a array like this:

```
Excel => [
          [ ""         , "11" , "12" , "13" ],  <- headers
          [ "08/2011"  ,  1   , 2    , 3    ]   <- first line
                                              ]
```

The goal here is pass the output to `node-xlsx` in order to create a excel spreadsheet.

I was able to create a mockup:

```js
let headers = ['', ];
let data = [headers];
let body = [];

let papas = {
    "11": {
     "08/2011": 1
    },
    "12": {
     "08/2011": 2
    },
    "13": {
     "08/2011": 3
    }
};

for (let cnpjs in papas) {
 headers.push(cnpjs);
}

let x = {};

for (let cnpj in papas) {
 Object.keys(papas[cnpj]).forEach((lasanha, index) => {
  if (typeof x[lasanha] !== 'number') {
   x[lasanha] = index;
   data.push(body);
   body.push(lasanha);
  } else {
   lasanha = lasanha;
  }
  body.push(papas[cnpj][lasanha]);
 });
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

The problem is, inputs like this:

```
{
  "11": {
    "08/2011": 1
    "09/2011": 1
  },
  "12": {
    "08/2011": 2
  },
  "13": {
    "08/2011": 3
  }
}
```

Will mess the logic, outputting things like:

```
[
 [ ""        , "11" , "12"      , "13"         ],
 [ "08/2011" , 1    , "09/2011" , 1    ,  2, 3 ],
 [ "09/2011" , 1    , "09/2011" , 1    ,  2, 3 ] ]
```

When it should:

```
 [
   [ ""         , "11" , "12" , "13" ],
   [ "08/2011"  ,  1   , 2    , 3    ],
   [ "09/2011"  ,  1                 ]
                                       ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

Update:

Is not it, but it comes closer ... when I have input like this:

```
{
  "11": {
    "08/2011": 1,
    "09/2011": 1
  },
  "12": {
    "08/2011": 2,
    "10/2011": 1
  },
  "13": {
    "08/2011": 3
  }
}
```

The outputs should be:

```
[ [ ''         , '11' , '12' , '13' ],
  [ '08/2011'  , 1    , 2    , 3    ],
  [ '09/2011'  , 1                  ],
  [ '10/2011'  ,      , 1           ] ]
```

The 10/2011 belongs to 12 in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and two `forEach()` loops. Note: `that` refers to `this` in first loop which is object as optional `thisArg` parameter.

```js
var input = {
  "11": {
    "08/2011": 1,
    "09/2011": 1
  },
  "12": {
    "08/2011": 2,
    "10/2011": 1
  },
  "13": {
    "08/2011": 3
  }
}

var result = [];
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(k, i) {
  (i == 0) ? result.push(['', k]): result[0].push(k);
  var that = this;
  Object.keys(input[k]).forEach(function(e) {
    if (!that[e]) {
      that[e] = [e];
      result.push(that[e]);
    }
    that[e][i + 1] = input[k][e];
  })
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// It was hard to write, it should be hard to understand.
const transform = input => [
  ['', ...Object.keys(input)]
 ,...[].concat(...Object.values(input).map(Object.keys))
    .filter((x, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) === i)
    .map(first => [first, ...Object.values(input).map(x =>
       Object.entries(x).find(([key, value]) => key === first)).map(x => x && x[1])])]

console.log(transform({
  "11": {
    "08/2011": 1,
    "09/2011": 1
  },
  "12": {
    "08/2011": 2,
    "10/2011": 1
  },
  "13": {
    "08/2011": 3
  }
}))
```